# Oracle Integration Cloud runtime error OSB-380000

Tags: java, soap, cloud, integration

While executing the integration in **SOAPUI**, the following error is shown in the response..

[image]

What is this erroe code "**OSB-380000**" and how to solve this?c

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle's KB, the OSB service is [failing to establish a connection](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2389472_1.html) to a downstream resource.

Comment: // TODO find out why it fails